# Chi squared density implies Chi squared distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X^2$. I showed that the density of $Y$ is exactly the same that of obtained from a Chi-squared distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

Is it sufficient to conclude that $Y\sim \chi^2_1$?

I know that the same probability distribution can be associated to different densities. But I'm not sure if a density can be associated to different distributions.

Comment: The answer is yes. The density of a real random variable fully characterizes its distribution.

Furthermore, in that case, the way you defined the random variable $Y$ [precisely matches the most common definition of a chi-squared variable with one degree of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ have density $p$, then for any $c\in\mathbb R$ we have $$\mu_1((-\infty,c))=\int_{-\infty}^c p(x)dx = \mu_2((-\infty,c)).$$ Therefore $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ agree on the open intervals $(-\infty,c)$ for all $c$. It follows by the uniqueness part of [Caratheodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) that $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

Comment: You argued that if $d$ is the density associated to two probability measures, than both are the same.

Comment: On the other hand, a probability distribution may admit distinct densities. However, these densities have to be equivalent in the sense that they differ only on sets of zero probability.

Comment: @CelineHarumi Yes, and therefore two different distributions cannot have the same density, which was your question.